# Invalid desktop entry file: '/usr/share/application/gzdoom.desktop' error when trying to run gzdoom

Tags: error-handling

I'm using this website:
https://github.com/jun-ro/Chromebook-VM
to run Ubuntu in my browser, now I had to get gdebi to install deb files, but whenever I try to run gzdoom I get the error `invalid desktop entry file: '/usr/share/application/gzdoom.desktop'`

I don't know how to fix this error, have tried to use ZDL to run Doom, but it won't launch because of this error.

When I run `-la /usr/share/applications/gzdoom.desktop` I get the text   `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 170 nov 8 2014 /usr/share/applications/gzdoom.desktop`

When I run cat `/usr/share/applications/GZDoom.desktop` I get the text

```
[Desktop Entry]Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=GZDoom
Comment=Advanced Doom Source Port
Exec=gzdoom
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gzdoom.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Game
```

When I try to launch any Doom wad files with zdl it just won't launch with gzdoom.

I put the wad files in `~/.config/gzdoom`/ and tried to run gzdoom, bit I still got the same invalid desktop entry file error.

Comment: Change `Categories=Game` to `Categories=Game;`

Comment: Try moving `Version=1.0` to a new line